# Mounting equipment that only occupies half the depth of the cabinet?

Tags: datacenter, physical-environment, rack

I'm a bit naïve at all of this (sorry!), but I have to install a bunch of equipment in our co-location facility.

We have [a switch](http://www.juniper.net/uk/en/products-services/switching/ex-series/ex4300/) that only occupies half the "depth" of the cabinet. How do I mount this? Is attaching it with the front screws only (like I might for a much lighter KVM) sufficient? It doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Do I need to buy some sort of bracket to fix it to?

Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you: [Mounting an EX4300 Switch on Two Posts of a Rack or Cabinet](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/task/installation/ex4300-mounting-on-two-post-rack-or-cabinet.html):

1. Use the 2 mounting brackets and 8 mounting screws (provided in the accessory box shipped with the switch)

[image: mounting brackets]

2. Mount the Switch on Two Posts of a Rack

[image: Mount the Switch on Two Posts]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 1U switch that is 25 to 30 cm deep, that will mount fine with four cage nuts.  If it's deeper then you may see it sag towards the back.  Whether you care about that or not is up to you.  Some cisco devices used to have extra brackets available so you could mount them at front and back and I assume that that sort of thing is still available.  Other devices allow you to mount the ears further back on the device to be closer to the balance point, but then the device sticks out, sometimes too far.  A taller device is less of an issue.

Comment: Thanks very much – very helpful to know that the sagging is not a problem.